# format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[0]’

Tags: c, arrays

I wanted to create a program where you would give input and it would give an output based on the input, but I've been having some trouble with the input part. I first made an uninitialized string and wanted the input to be stored in it. But when I compile, it shows this error:

> format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[0]’

I've looked online, but was not able to get an answer on how to fix this.

My code so far below (In C):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char string[] = "";
    scanf("%c", &string);
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? Both gcc and clang say `char (*)[1]`, not `char (*)[0]`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `%s`? In any case, do note that the `string` variable as declared is only 1 byte in size and hence cannot store any valid string except the empty string.

Comment: You should not get that message for this code, please check you are compiling exactly what you posted

Comment: The compiler I use is gcc @Joseph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&string` is a pointer to an array, just passing `string` is sufficient. `string` has length 1 and will fit a single character, but don't try to interpret it as a string because it will not be null-terminated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char string[] = "";
    scanf("%c", string);
}
```

Alternatively, you could do this. It is equivalent and some say it is more readable.

```
int main() {
    char string[] = "";
    scanf("%c", &string[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem statement is "I wanted to create a program where you would give input and it would give an output based on the input"

You can try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LEN 50

int main(){
    char string[MAX_LEN+1];

    //fgets is safe & would read whitespaces
    fgets(string, MAX_LEN, stdin);
    printf("%s", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets(string, MAX_LEN, stdin)` --> `fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin)`. The `fgets()` function reads at most one less than the maximum number specified, leaving room for the `\0` terminator.

Answer (score -1):

regarding;

```
scanf("%c", &string);
```

The variable `string` is an array.  In C, a 'bare' reference to an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  So, the call to `scanf()` parameter `&string` is asking for the address of an address.

Usually the compiler will output a warning (as you have seen) but will produce the correct code.   To avoid this problem, remove the `&` from the parameter when the parameter is a 'bare' reference to an array.  I.E.

```
scanf("%c", string);
```

Even better, use:

```
scanf("%c", &string[0]);
```

For robust code, always check the returned value from any of the `scanf()` family of functions.  In general, they return the number of successful input format conversion specifiers.  so an even better example would be;

```
if( scanf("%c", &string[0]) != 1 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "scanf for first char of array -string- failed" );
}
```

This kind of error is (usually) not recoverable, so normally the code would be:

```
if( scanf("%c", &string[0]) != 1 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "scanf for first char of array -string- failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

where both `exit()` and EXIT_FAILURE are exposed in the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: "_the call to `scanf()` parameter `&string` is asking for the address of an address_" -- in C an array expression decays to a pointer to the first element (not the first byte) of the array in most expressions, but not when it is the operand to the unary `&` address operator (or when it is the operand to `sizeof`, or when it is a string literal used to initialize another array). So, `&string` takes the address of `string[]` (the array), not the address of a pointer to the first element. The error message complains about this with `argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[0]’`.

Comment: @exnihilo,  Please address the usability of my answer and not get wrapped up in the semantics of how I expressed a detail.   Also, if you think there is a difference between the 'address of the first byte' and the 'address of the first element' in an array, then please explain why you think there is a difference

Comment: My comment did address the usability of your answer. Misunderstandings about arrays vs. pointers and array-to-pointer decay abound on this site, and answers should be correct in the details. Your statement "_`&string` is asking for the address of an address_" is absolutely wrong, and this kind of misstatement can only lead to problems for learners.

Comment: Yes, the address of the first byte and the address of the first element are the same, but arrays do _not_ decay to the address of the first byte, rather they decay to a _pointer_ to the first element of the array. This pointer is not a pointer to the first byte, but a pointer to the first element. The difference is in the type of the pointer, and you can certainly tell the difference when pointer arithmetic is attempted.

Comment: `&string` is not the address of an address .